# Why did my question asking about a java implementation of diazo get closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

I posted a question about the diazo library (http://docs.diazo.org). Asking if anybody knows of an implementation in java.

I've compared my question with a lot of questions in stackoverflow and I do not see what is wrong with my question.

I consider my question having following form:

A library L is implemented in a language/platform P.
Is there any implementation of L in another language/platform, e.g. in platform R?

I flagged two times asking why the question was closed. But no answer or hint.

What did I do wrong in my question? Here is the link to my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348234/does-anybody-know-a-java-implementation-of-diazo

Comment: Asking for an implementation is a shopping list question.

Comment: Please see this question: [Why did my question asking what the best software to make 2D games with get closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166762/why-did-my-question-asking-what-the-best-software-to-make-2d-games-with-get-clos) ... We just discussed this (again).

Comment: Also, Diazo can be used as a plugin into the front-end server to style different backends, whatever the implementation of the backend. It's like asking for a Java version of nginx: why care at all, just run it?

Comment: If a developer working with a opensource library in python (e.g. diazo) needs to do a similar work in java and he/she wants to know if there is a similar library in java. How can this be a shopping list question? Or in other words how he/she should ask?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you for the hint. I had expected answers like yours in stackoverflow instead of closing the question as no-question.

Comment: That's the point; *not here*. It is a shopping question because there could be many answers. In this case I think there are 0, but potentially you end up with a list of opinionated recommendations.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your comments.